# Get the parents for a folder by its name with JSOM or REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

there's a way for get all the parents for a folder ?

I've for example a structure of folders like this:

```
folder 1    
   folder 1A    
   folder 1B 
folder 2    
   folder 2A
     folder 2A1
```

what i need is to get all the parents for folder2A1 which looks like so: folder2/folder2A

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you already know how to use REST? If so I think the property you are looking for is **FileRef**. So this end point

```
http://<site>/_api/lists/getbytitle('<listname>')/items?$select=FileRef
```

That will return a value like

```
/<site>/<listname>/<parent folders if any>/<item name>
```

You can use `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` or some other string trick to remove the parts you don't want and then `split('/')` to get the remaining bits.